# compressing font files in amazon s3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, compression, boto3

I am using Amazon S3 to serve static files for my website. My server side code is built on Django 2.0. I am using boto3 and django-storages packages to server static files. AWS_IS_GZIPPED is set to True in settings.py file.

All the static files (CSS, JS, images) are compressed. Response header has content-encoding as gzip for these requests. But, font files are not getting compressed. Is there a different way to compress font files when served from S3?

You can clearly see this behaviour when you inspect my website. [Click here](https://www.blockchainsemantics.com/) to go to the website.

Answer (score 0):

"https://blockchainsemantics.s3.amazonaws.com/static/fonts/NexaBold.c9f309b3d479.otf" This is one of your font files from your website, you check response headers for the font request, you will see it is as **application/octet-stream** MIME type, which will not get compressed while getting served from S3 or CloudFront, you can check the supported compression MIME types of CloudFront here "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html", If you are worried about performance, serve static files Through a CDN like CloudFront, it will cache the object in edge location.

Comment: Yeah. CDNs are fine. I was looking for ways to render compressed font files. Looks like there isn't any way out.